# Java method chaining suggestion

Tags: java, android, chaining, method-chaining

I understand that a method chaining can be made by following:

```
public Mind increment(){
        this.age++;
        return this;
    }
```

but if i would test this, it would allow me to call the chain like this:

```
rf.increment().increment().increment();
```

and as i have seen from e.g. `Toast.MakeText()`, it doesn't recommend "MakeText" as method call again. Any idea how that is done?

Comment: It is probably because `makeText()` is a static method on `Toast`. After you have called it, your IDE will probably recommend only the instance-methods on `Toast`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @marstran that should be an answer, because makeText() as far as i'm concerned is static.

Comment: Exactly what @marstran said. `makeText` wasn't designed for chaining. it does not return this; it returns a brand new instance. Take a look [at the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-0/android/widget/Toast.java#Toast.makeText%28android.content.Context%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%2Cint%29).

Answer (score 1):

@marstran and @flkes pointed out the answer; makeText() is a static method on Toast, and itself doesn't return "this", but a new instance.